How can I use a Bluetooth microphone in Flutter for Android during video recording?
Problem:
I'm developing a video recording app using Flutter, and I want to capture audio from a Bluetooth microphone (model: S280) during the recording instead of using the built-in device microphone. However, the app defaults to the device microphone even when the Bluetooth microphone is paired and available.
Goal:
I want to switch the audio input to the Bluetooth microphone when it's paired and use it as the audio source during video recording.
Bluetooth Code in Kotlin (Android):
I attempted to set the Bluetooth microphone as the default input device by using the AudioManager and enabling Bluetooth SCO (SCO is used for audio connections). Here's the code I used in my MainActivity:
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.content.Context
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    private val TAG = "BluetoothDebug"  // For debugging

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        // Register a new method channel to communicate with the Flutter app
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "example.com/channel").setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "switchToBluetoothMicrophone" -> {
                    switchToBluetoothMicrophone(result)
                }
                else -> {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun switchToBluetoothMicrophone(result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        // Get the Bluetooth adapter
        val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth is not supported on this device.")
            result.error("BLUETOOTH_NOT_SUPPORTED", "Bluetooth is not supported on this device.", null)
            return
        }

        // Ensure that Bluetooth is enabled on the device
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth is not enabled.")
            result.error("BLUETOOTH_DISABLED", "Bluetooth is not enabled on the device.", null)
            return
        }

        // Get a list of paired Bluetooth devices
        val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice> = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
        if (pairedDevices.isEmpty()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No paired Bluetooth devices found.")
            result.error("NO_PAIRED_DEVICES", "No paired Bluetooth devices found.", null)
            return
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Paired Bluetooth devices:")
        var foundBluetoothMic = false
        // Iterate over the list of paired devices and find the Bluetooth microphone
        for (device in pairedDevices) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Device Name: ${device.name}, Device Address: ${device.address}, Class: ${device.bluetoothClass.deviceClass}")
            
            // Log Bluetooth Class for better debugging
            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth Device Class: ${device.bluetoothClass}")

            // Check if the device is a Bluetooth microphone (you may need to adjust this based on the actual device class)
            if (device.bluetoothClass.deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_MICROPHONE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Found Bluetooth microphone: ${device.name}")
                val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
                audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
                audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn = true
                audioManager.startBluetoothSco()
                audioManager.isMicrophoneMute = false
                audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = false

                foundBluetoothMic = true
                result.success("Bluetooth microphone activated.")
                break
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Not a microphone device: ${device.name}, Device Class: ${device.bluetoothClass.deviceClass}")
            }
        }

        if (!foundBluetoothMic) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No Bluetooth microphone found.")
            result.error("NO_BLUETOOTH_MIC", "No Bluetooth microphone found.", null)
        }
    }
}

class BluetoothAudioHelper {
  // Define the MethodChannel for platform communication
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('example.com/channel');

  // Method to switch to Bluetooth microphone
  static Future<void> switchToBluetoothMicrophone() async {
    try {
      // Attempt to invoke the native method
      await _channel.invokeMethod('switchToBluetoothMicrophone');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      // Handle any errors that occur during the method call
      print("Failed to switch to Bluetooth microphone: ${e.message}");
    }
  }
}
Future<void> startVideoRecording() async {
    if (!_isCameraInitialized || _isRecording) return; // Ensure it's not already recording

    try {
      // Switch to Bluetooth microphone before recording
      await BluetoothAudioHelper.switchToBluetoothMicrophone();

      await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();
      _isRecording = true;
      _mediaPath = null;
      _isCameraMode = false;
      startTimer();
      // Lock the orientation during recording to prevent black screen
      _setOrientationDuringRecording();
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error starting video recording: $e');
    }
  }  // Request required permissions
  Future<void> requestPermissions() async {
    var cameraStatus = await Permission.camera.request();
    var storageStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
    var microphoneStatus = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (cameraStatus.isGranted && storageStatus.isGranted && microphoneStatus.isGranted) {
      print("All permissions granted.");
    } else {
      print("Permissions not granted.");
    }
  }

  void initializeCamera(CameraDescription camera) async {
    try {
      _cameraController = CameraController(
        camera,
        ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh, // Adjust resolution
        enableAudio: true,
      );
      await _cameraController.initialize();
      _isCameraInitialized = true;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Camera initialization error: $e');
      _isCameraInitialized = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }

    _cameraController.addListener(() {
      if (_cameraController.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error: ${_cameraController.value.errorDescription}');
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

I/flutter ( 9568): Attempting to switch to Bluetooth microphone...
D/BluetoothDebug( 9568): Paired Bluetooth devices:
D/BluetoothDebug( 9568): Device Name: S280, Device Address: 55:55:55:66:B4:FE, Class: 1028
D/BluetoothDebug( 9568): Not a microphone device: S280, Device Class: 1028
E/BluetoothDebug( 9568): No Bluetooth microphone found.
I/flutter ( 9568): Failed to switch to Bluetooth microphone: No Bluetooth microphone found.
I/flutter ( 9568): Bluetooth microphone switch attempted.
I/flutter ( 9568): Starting video recording...
D/BluetoothDebug( 9568): Paired Bluetooth devices:
D/BluetoothDebug( 9568): Device Name: S280, Device Address: 55:55:55:66:B4:FE, Class: 1028
D/BluetoothDebug( 9568): Not a microphone device: S280, Device Class: 1028
E/BluetoothDebug( 9568): No Bluetooth microphone found.

